# Difference between "æ" and "a"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

The vowels "æ" and "a" sound the same to me. For example:

"æ" is used in words like "cat" or "hat"

"a" is used in words like "now" or "round"

It looks like "a" is only used in diphthongs. However, in American English they sound to me exactly the same to me. Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: Do you hear the difference between rat and route?

Comment: @The Photon  "route" isn't exactly a good comparison if you're from New England.

Comment: @Centaurus , yes I mean route when pronounced to rhyme with shout.

Comment: English doesn't use the vowel /a/, so you're not going to hear it in English words. You should listen to another language, like French, if you want to hear what /a/ sounds like. [Here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patte#French) is the word *patte* /pat/ in French, and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pat#English) is the word *pat* /pæt/ in English.

Comment: Most Americans pronounce _father_ with /a/, as well as _hot, rock, balm, bomb, Todd,_ and _Scotch_.  As you can see, it's used as a pure vowel as well as serving the base vowel in the /ay/ diphthong of _right, type, aisle_, and in the /aw/ diphthong of _rout_ or _out_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between them is not phonemic. Words like "now" and "round" are usually analyzed as containing a phonetic diphthong that acts like a single unitary vowel. So I would say that you shouldn't think of /aʊ/ as a sum of separate /a/ and /ʊ/ sounds.

The reason people use the symbol "a" in /aʊ/ vs. /æ/ in words like *cat* is in large part a matter of tradition.

In different accents, the sounds used may vary in different ways.

I think in general, the start of /aʊ/ will be phonetically further "back" than /æ/, but it depends on the context. For me, the start of /aʊ/ is a close match phonetically to the vowel /æ/ in /æl/, as vowels before /l/ are [backed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_articulation#Advanced_and_retracted) in my dialect. When I try to identify the start of /aʊ/ with a specific monophthong, I do find that the phoneme /æ/ feels like the best fit to me. But other speakers might feel differently.